# Yelp Web Scraping - Beautiful Soup and Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am very new to web scraping and am trying to get items under "Amenities and More" for one of my projects. As can be seen below I want to extract, Health Score Excellent, Offers delivery, Offers Takeout, etc." from a restaurant's Yelp page. I want to do this for several other restaurants yelp pages however for now I will settle on just figuring out this issue.

[image]

So far as I understood from different webpages I did following with no good result.

```
url='https://www.yelp.com/biz/ziggis-coffee-longmont'
yelp_page=requests.get(url)
yelp_soup=BeautifulSoup(yelp_page.content, 'lxml')
yelp_soup.find_all("span")
```

Result `[<span class="offscreen" id="page-content"> </span>]`

I am choosing 'span' as I see following when I click "inspect" over "Offers Takeout".

[image]

Other things I have tried are:

```
yelp_soup.find_all("span",{'class': "text__373c0__2Kxyz text-color--normal__373c0__3xep9 text-align--left__373c0__2XGa- text-weigt--semibold__373c0__h2l0fe text-size--large__373c0__3t60B"})
```

And

```
yelp_soup.find_all("span",{'class': "text__373c0__2Kxyz"})
```

Result: `[]`

Please suggest how to proceed.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried scraping this page on my end. It appears that `lxml` does not grasp the spans that you are looking for. I changed `lxml` to `html.parser`(python built-in tool for parsing HTML) and the `soup.find_all()` should work fine. Also, remember that when you scrape a class, you have to include the spaces that it in there too. (Note that there is a space at the beginning of the class in your screenshot.) Otherwise, BeautifulSoup will not be able to find the desired elements.

Here's the code that worked fine on my end:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url='https://www.yelp.com/biz/ziggis-coffee-longmont'
yelp_page=requests.get(url)
print(yelp_page.status_code)
yelp_soup=BeautifulSoup(yelp_page.content, 'html.parser')
spans = yelp_soup.find_all("span")

print(yelp_soup.find_all('span', class_=" text__373c0__2Kxyz text-color--normal__373c0__3xep9 text-align--left__373c0__2XGa- text-weight--semibold__373c0__2l0fe text-size--large__373c0__3t60B"))
```

Response:

```
[<span class=" text__373c0__2Kxyz text-color--normal__373c0__3xep9 text-align--left__373c0__2XGa- text-weight--semibold__373c0__2l0fe text-size--large__373c0__3t60B">Drive-thru</span>, <span class=" text__373c0__2Kxyz text-color--normal__373c0__3xep9 text-align--left__373c0__2XGa- text-weight--semibold__373c0__2l0fe text-size--large__373c0__3t60B">Delivery</span>, <span class=" text__373c0__2Kxyz text-color--normal__373c0__3xep9 text-align--left__373c0__2XGa- text-weight--semibold__373c0__2l0fe text-size--large__373c0__3t60B">Takeout</span>, <span class=" text__373c0__2Kxyz text-color--normal__373c0__3xep9 text-align--left__373c0__2XGa- text-weight--semibold__373c0__2l0fe text-size--large__373c0__3t60B"><a class=" link__373c0__1G70M link-color--blue-dark__373c0__85-Nu link-size--inherit__373c0__1VFlE" href="/inspections/ziggis-coffee-longmont" name="" rel="" target="">Health Score</a></span>, <span class=" text__373c0__2Kxyz text-color--normal__373c0__3xep9 text-align--left__373c0__2XGa- text-weight--semibold__373c0__2l0fe text-size--large__373c0__3t60B">Offers Delivery</span>, <span class=" text__373c0__2Kxyz text-color--normal__373c0__3xep9 text-align--left__373c0__2XGa- text-weight--semibold__373c0__2l0fe text-size--large__373c0__3t60B">Offers Takeout</span>, <span class=" text__373c0__2Kxyz text-color--normal__373c0__3xep9 text-align--left__373c0__2XGa- text-weight--semibold__373c0__2l0fe text-size--large__373c0__3t60B">Accepts Credit Cards</span>, <span class=" text__373c0__2Kxyz text-color--normal__373c0__3xep9 text-align--left__373c0__2XGa- text-weight--semibold__373c0__2l0fe text-size--large__373c0__3t60B"><a class=" link__373c0__1G70M link-color--blue-dark__373c0__85-Nu link-size--inherit__373c0__1VFlE" href="/questions/Loqh-rc9CJiQEfS_EUE6ow/InzxYWdgCbaIpytQEjqxGQ" name="" rel="" role="link" target="">Answer this question</a></span>]
```

[image: Response]

**EDIT**: If the above code didn't work, try

```py
print(yelp_soup.find_all('span', {"class": " text__373c0__2Kxyz text-color--normal__373c0__3xep9 text-align--left__373c0__2XGa- text-weight--semibold__373c0__2l0fe text-size--large__373c0__3t60B"}))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I copy/pasted your code in my jupyter notebook and its still giving me empty list at the end. Any other idea on how to approach this issue?

Comment: Hi, in this case, I would directly print yelp_soup.prettify() and find the element I want to find there.  Find the class name for your desired element and double-check the class names. (In some cases, the class names can be different)

Comment: I also added an edit in my answer above and try if the alternative works.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to get the whole span data by executing spans variable. I need to ask one more question on how to get <span> tagged data after expanding "Show More" button, but I will do that in another thread. Thanks again